Linked-list population via recursion in C++
I want to learn pointers and referencing them.
I will use the following task for example.
I need to populate the linked-list defined below from the given number, where each digit is list's nodes.
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;

    ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
};

The number is 1234.
Therefore the linked list is supposed to look like:  4 -> 3 -> 2-> 1.
I have implemented a function that utilizes recursion to set value and next node.
void nodeFromNumber(int& number, ListNode* node) {
        node->val = number % 10;
        if (number) {
            ListNode newNode {};
            node->next = &newNode ;

            number /= 10;
            nodeFromNumber(number, &newNode );
        }
    }

The problem seems that I cannot set correct pointer from node->next to actual node. I want to learn more on the pointers topic, and it looks like I have a problem understanding why setting pointer to newly created node object's memory address (as far as I understand it has been allocated properly) resolves in error. After walking through list and printing node's value via printList function, I get that first node stores correct value however the rest does not (even though I recursively set newNode->val).
I will provide full program below.
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void nodeFromNumber(int& number, ListNode* node) {
    if (number) {
        node->val = number % 10;
        ListNode newNode {};
        node->next = &newNode;
        number /= 10;
        nodeFromNumber(number, &newNode);
    }
}

void printList(ListNode* node) {
    if (node == nullptr) {
        cout << "\nlist ended";    
    } else {
        cout << node->val << endl;
        printList(node->next);
    }
}

int main()
{   
    ListNode node1 {ListNode(3)};
    ListNode node2 {ListNode(3, &node1)};
    ListNode headOdList{ListNode(9, &node2)};

    int number { 1234 };
    ListNode head{};
    nodeFromNumber(number, &head);
    
    cout<<"\nList:\n";
    //case A
    //printList(&head);
    //case B
    printList(&headOdList);
    return 0;
}

Case A: is printing manually created linked list.

Case B: is printing the generated linked list, the issue is that it is running in a forever loop, and the second node in the list has random value.

Can you help me investigate this?

You are probably at a stage where you need to learn about object lifetimes.  You are pointing to objects that get destroyed as soon as you leave an if statement.  Do you understand when newNode begins existing and when it no longer exists?

The assignment node->next = &newNode is wrong. It will make next point to the local variable newNode. Once the function returns and the variable goes out of scope, the pointer will become invalid.

It's also worth mentioning that if you turn on your compiler warnings, you will be told of mistakes like these.  You absolutely want to enable and read the warnings that your compiler can give you.

Once the allocation stuff gets fixed, you'll still have an extra 0 on the end of your list.

If the null pointer represents an empty list, all your non-empty lists will have a 0 as their last element. This is probably not what you intended.

@DrewDormann, Thank you for the tip! I though that storing reference to the Node will keep that memory allocated as there is object that has reference to it (from these answers I realised that there is no such thing as garbage collection in c++).
@Someprogrammerdude as far as Ii see, there is no way to make these recursive, as it requires some local creation as storage (in my current knowladge base, haev not yet explored alloc and dealloc).
@ScottHunter thank you for report, i did rewrite it in swift. No issues there (fixed by moving zero-check above initialization of new Node)

@molbdnilo fixed in example by moving initialization below zero-check (default 0 is required as I am learning C++ while solving leetCode so they provided me this struct as is)

Get your new nodes with  new.

@busido I am learning C++ while solving leetCode  -- That's your main mistake.  Do not use leetcode to learn C++.  The purpose of Leetcode is for experienced C++ programmers to spend time solving their problems.   If you had no idea about object lifetimes and C++ basics such as this, then you shouldn't be trying to solve problems with one of the most difficult computer languages.  Instead, get an actual C++ book.

@PaulMcKenzie I am learning the language on learncpp.com and leetCode for practicing what I have learned by trying to solve easy tasks

what I have learned by trying to solve easy tasks -- First, trying to manipulate a linked list is not an "easy task" if you don't know the computer language you will be using to accomplish the task.  Second, you definitely missed the entire section of learncpp.com that talked about the basics.  Third, it still stands that the questions on Leetcode (and other sites like it) are designed for experienced people who have the relative experience in the computer language they are using to solve the problem.

Also, do not use swift or any other computer language as a model in trying to learn or write C++.  If you use another computer language as a model in learning C++, this will lead to 1) Buggy programs, 2) Inefficient programs, and 3) Programs that will look weird to a C++ programmer.  Pretend that swift, Java, or whatever other language does not exist if you are actually trying to learn C++.

@trincot thank you for tip! it worked. I will look up why this have worked and when to delete it properly
@PaulMcKenzie you are right, I will investigate further this topic, thank you for help

Writing a proper and idiomatic C++ linked list looks nothing like this. Pointers are the parallel parking of C++. Not actually that complicated, but everyone makes it seem bigger and scarier than it is.

The main issue is that you make a next member point to the address of a local variable, which will no longer be a valid address once the function returns.
Create your nodes with new instead.
Also, since you have a constructor that takes arguments for value and a next pointer, you can reduce your code quite a bit.
It will also be more elegant if you don't require that the caller of your function must provide the first node. Instead, let the function return the list it has created.
Suggested code:
ListNode* nodeFromNumber(int number) {
    return new ListNode(
        number % 10, 
        number / 10 ? nodeFromNumber(number / 10) : nullptr
    );
}

In your main code you could use it like this:
    ListNode *head = nodeFromNumber(1234);
    printList(head);

Don't forget to delete the nodes if you are in control of the complete program. If you're just writing a function on a code challenge site and it has to return the list, then you'd of course not delete the nodes and leave that for the platform code to clean up.
